# Android App started crashing from Android Studio on device

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

I'm working on an android app since 6 month ago and I was using my LG G3 to debug and test from Android Studio all this time. My device has Android 4.4.2 which is not one of the newest version but I haven't got a problem like this before.

A couple of days ago my app started crashing every time I launch it from Android Studio even when the same version on Play Store works fine. What seems odd is that the app crashes and show the message that it has stopped, I tap OK and some seconds after the message shows up again.

Here is the stack trace of the crash which seems to be unrelated.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.gl.senza.staging, PID: 14749
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]
at com.gl.senza.SenzaApplication.onCreate(SenzaApplication.java:54)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4430)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:142)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The same code works perfect on other devices and emulators and it started crashing on my LG G3 suddenly. Any help will be strongly appreciated

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32097909/1827254

Comment: Just realized that if I'm on release mode with minifyEnabled true the app compiles and works well, but when on debug mode with minifyEnabled false the app crashes on launch. @Eselfar the solution on that post didn't work

Comment: @TomasTiminskas Hi Tom, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: @LêTháiPhúcQuang No so far. I had to replace my device with another one and everything worked well. Not sure if there was some issue on the operative system of my old device but it never worked again